# Debug using attach to process of windows installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, visual-studio-debugging

I have my *.msi* windows installer project with multiple services to install. I have a `NullReferenceException` during installation and I would like to debug installation process to figure out what is going on. I tried **Debug > attach to process** but it didn't hit any breakpoint. `Debugger.Break()` didn't help me as well. Can somebody explain how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `Debugger.Launch();` to my `public override void Install(IDictionary savedState)` and it solved my problem. Now I can debug using *attach to process* feature.